# Add new user to database

Tags: c#, sql

Hello can you help me with this

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Byte[] IMAGES = null;
    FileStream STREAM = new FileStream(IMGLOCATION, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    BinaryReader BSR = new BinaryReader(STREAM);
    IMAGES = BSR.ReadBytes((int)STREAM.Length);

    CON.Open();
    string SQLQUERY = "INSERT INTO USERS (FULNAME,USERNAME,PASSWORD,IMAGE,STATUS)VALUES('"+textBox2.Text+"','"+textBox1.Text+"'.'"+textBox3.Text+ "',@IMG,'" + textBox4.Text + "')";
    CMD = new SqlCommand(SQLQUERY,CON);
    CMD.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@IMG", IMAGES));
    int N = CMD.ExecuteNonQuery();
    CON.Close();
    MessageBox.Show("USER CREATED SUCCESSFULLY");
}
```

I tried to put image on the end still same error when I try to create new user with password `12345`

> Incorrect syntax near '12345

Comment: check the constructed sql query by putting a breakpoint. keep in mind that you should be using parameters, not concatenating the sql directly from user input,

Comment: You have a period instead of a comma between the username and password values. Also, you should use parameterized queries, otherwise it is prone to SQL injection.

Comment: The error message said: Check your Syntax! Did you check it? And: Be aware of SQL-Injection!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is simply syntax; you had a period instead of a comma at `textBox1.Text+"'.'"+textBox3.Text`

The other issue is that you **need** to use parameterized queries.

Here is your code updated to use parameterization...

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Byte[] IMAGES = null;
    FileStream STREAM = new FileStream(IMGLOCATION, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    BinaryReader BSR = new BinaryReader(STREAM);
    IMAGES = BSR.ReadBytes((int)STREAM.Length);

    CON.Open();
    string SQLQUERY = "INSERT INTO USERS (FULNAME,USERNAME,PASSWORD,IMAGE,STATUS)VALUES(@name, @username, @password, @IMG, @status)";
    CMD = new SqlCommand(SQLQUERY,CON);
    CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", textBox2.Text);
    CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", textBox1.Text);
    CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", textBox3.Text);
    CMD.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@IMG", IMAGES));
    CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", textBox4.Text);
    int N = CMD.ExecuteNonQuery();
    CON.Close();
    MessageBox.Show("USER CREATED SUCCESSFULLY");
}
```

Another side issue is that you're not encrypting the password, but I'm guessing you'll get to that eventually or just took it out for the sake of creating a minimal question.

Comment: Thanks for the code and i did took it out thankss again

Answer (score 5):

```
... +textBox1.Text+"'.'"+textBox3.Text+ ...
                     ^
                     |
          change this dot to comma
```

And after that I'd suggest to rewrite your query to use parameters for all injected values.

Comment: thanks Dmitry such a small mistake costed me 2-3 hours thanks again

Answer (score 3):

I think you need comma between TextBox1 and TextBox3

```
string SQLQUERY = "INSERT INTO USERS (FULNAME,USERNAME,PASSWORD,IMAGE,STATUS)VALUES('"+textBox2.Text+"','"+textBox1.Text+"','"+textBox3.Text+ "',@IMG,'" + textBox4.Text + "')";
```